# Writing datas to memobox from .txt file using Lazarus freepascal?

Tags: pascal, lazarus, freepascal

I've got a project at schools which requires to write datas from a .txt file to a "memobox" in Lazarus freepascal.
There are datas in order like this.

Budapest tomato 23
Dublin tv 45
Rosslare projector 43

etc.

I have to read these datas from a .txt file and then write them into a memobox in Lazarus freepascal.
If I am not mistaken I have already copyed the datas from the .txt file but I have no idea how to write them.

I've already written this code:

```
type
cityname:integer;
product:string;
quantity:integer;
var
Form1: TForm1;
ceg:array[1..5] of rektip;
db:integer;

implementation
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var f:textfile; i:integer; a:char;
begin
assignfile(f,'termek.txt');
reset(f);
readln(f,db);
While not eof(f) do
begin
  readln(f,ceg[i].varosnev,a,ceg[i].termek,a,ceg[i].darabszam);
end;
db:=1;
closefile(f);
end;           


procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var i:integer;
begin
For i:=1 to db do
Memo1.lines.add(ceg[i].varosnev,ceg[i].termek,IntToStr(ceg[i].darabszam));
end;
end;
```

I would like to know how to fix it.

Comment: This exact question is that I do not know how to write these datas into memobox.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is incomplete, so I assume:

```
type
  rektip = record
    varosnev: string;
    termek: string;
    darabszam: Integer;
  end;
```

There is a lot wrong with your approach:

```
readln(f,db);
While not eof(f) do
begin
  readln(f,ceg[i].varosnev,a,ceg[i].termek,a,ceg[i].darabszam);
end;
db:=1;
closefile(f);
end;
```

You are not initializing nor updating `i`, so you are reading all data into the same record, and you don't even know which one (`i` could be 100 and you'd be writing the data to *somewhere* unknown -- there is no `ceg[100]`). That results in undefined behaviour (and that can be a crash too).

Do something like:

```
var
  ceg: array of rektip; 

...

begin
  AssignFile(f, 'termek.txt');
  Reset(f);
  Readln(f, db);
  if db = 0 then
    Exit;
  SetLength(ceg, db);
  i := 0;
  while not eof(f) do
  begin
    Readln(f, ceg[i].varosnev, ceg[i].termek, ceg[i].darabszam);
    Inc(i);
    if i > High(ceg) then
      Break;
  end;
  SetLength(ceg, i); // remove any empty slots.
  CloseFile(f);
end;
```

Now you can put them into the TMemo:

```
for i := Low(ceg) to High(ceg) do
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('%s %s %d', [ceg[i].varosnev, ceg[i].termek, ceg[i].darabszam])); 
end;
```

Note that the code above, reading from the file, assumes the file looks like:

```
3
Budapest tomato 23
Dublin tv 45
Rosslare projector 43
```

i.e. each "record" is on a line of its own and the first line contains the number of records.